# Display content when user clicks a button. User can click multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add content to a page when they click a button. Customer is giving me a list and it could be 3 or 300 long. I dont want to have 300 form fields for every person. How can a create a script that when they click a button it will add the form field again and again and again and again or however many times they click it.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Here's an example: `$('.add').on('click', function(){ $('form .person:last').append('<input type="text" class="person" />'); });`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple.

```
$("#idofbutton").click(function() {
    var inputElement = "<input type='text' />";
    $("#idOfContainer").append(inputElement);
});
```